# VS IDE setting, for more code real estate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, optimization, ide

So here's the issue, i've removed just about everything i've found in the program- but i can not figure out for the life of me how to remove the useless whitespace that was where the line numbers were, which is completely irrelevant to me, you are basically losing 1/8th of the entire screen to useless whitespace in this IDE, and i'd like to remove it, but i dont see a setting for it, does anyone know where it is ? - basically you can see on the red lines what i mean to remove, also does anybody know how to remove the blue little extra bar? Also useless to me. Thankyou to whoever can point me to a setting where i can switch off this and retrieve some of my lost screen real-estate.

[image]

Comment: With 3 tab-groups open and 120% zoom, that takes up a lot of space... The reason that is there is for the change info (yellow/green lines) and the hint icons. Try opening Options>Settings>Text Editor and disabling "Track Changes", "Selection Margin" and "Indicator Margin"

Comment: High resolution, i know what its for, thanks though - also the zoom that high was me testing something, i use 109 most of the time. Didnt think i'd have to explain that. 

And yes, with a big screen, 3 tabs make lots of sense because i can edit several referring codes at once, and be able to switch between them with ease

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That area is for the Intellisense "Hint" icon, the track changes, selection margin, and indicator margin. Those settings are found by opening Tools > Options > Text Editor > General:

[image]

Here is what my IDE looked like before deselecting them:

[image]

And then after:

[image]

Comment: You're a hero, a gentleman and a scholar. And certainly smarter than i.

Comment: The amount of settings/customization can be staggering, and what the different parts of the IDE are called are not well-documented as far as I can tell, so a lot of this is playing around with settings until you find the one that works. There is still a bit of space there between the folding and the edge that I'm not sure what setting controls, but at least you are closer.

Comment: It can also change with updates, for example when I updated to the latest, Microsoft thought it would be great to turn on the code-inspector view that takes up about 1" on the right side, so now I have to find that setting again and disable it.